# How to validate form which accepts only (any)image type files?

Tags: javascript, jsp, validation

Here i have demo.jsp page where i'm uploading the image for this i have written javascript validation code for jpg,png and gif but if image type is other than that we cant write for every type in conditon so is there any alternate method to do this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>ImageResizing</title>
    <script>
        function  vlidate() {
            var fileName = document.getElementById("Imgfile").value;
            var file_extension = fileName.split('.').pop();
            var newWidth = document.getElementById("newWidth").value;
            var newHeight = document.getElementById("newHeight").value;
            //alert(fileName);
            //alert(file_extension);                
            if (file_extension !== "jpg" || file_extension !== "png" || file_extension !== "gif") {
                alert("Choose Valid image");
            }
            else if ((file_extension == "jpg" || file_extension == "png" || file_extension == "gif") && (newWidth.length != "" && newHeight.length != "")) {
                //alert("Go ahead");
                document.getElementById("uploadImgForm").submit();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ABD3EB">
    <%
        out.println("<form method='post' action='FileUploadServlet' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='uploadImgForm' name='uploadImgForm'>");
        out.println("<h2>Image Resizing</h2>");
        out.println("<table>");
        out.println("<tr><td><input type='file' id='Imgfile' name='Imgfile'></td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td></td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td>New Width:</td><td><input type='text'  id='newWidth' name='newWidth'</td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td>New Height:</td><td><input type='text' id='newHeight' name='newHeight'</td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td></td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td><input type='button' value='Upload Image' onclick='vlidate()' ></td></tr>");
        //out.println("<tr><td><input type='submit' value='Upload Image' ></td></tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</form>");
    %>
</body>
```

Comment: @pradnyapalan, do not answer questions through edits.

Comment: validation of image file goes far beyond validating the extension.

Answer (score 0):

you can have an accept attribute in the input tag

```
<input type="file" name="imagefilename" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" />

<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

the first one works for chrome ,whereas the second one works for chrome and FF

refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828554/how-to-allow-input-type-file-to-accept-only-image-files)

To create a file input box that allows with multiple file support you can simply do

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="File1" id="File1" accept="image/*" />
```

Comment: if image other than png,gif,jpeg then?

Comment: <input type="file" accept="image/*"> in jsp ,what can i write in js?

Comment: Could you please change my code,i'm little bit confusing

Comment: if we have written accept="image/*" then in js it will check only whether jpg,png ,gif else it will show upload correct image right?if i have uploaded bmp format then it shows wrong ?

Comment: if you give accpet="image/*" ,it will accept even the bmp format images. have a look at the MIME type available for the images,as well as this [link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/06/Using-the-HTML5-input-typefile-multiplemultiple-Tag-in-ASPNET) you will have a clear idea