# How to filter a FileList object chosen by directory choser in Javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to filter or remove some file from FileList object. I have gotten a FileList object form directory chooser.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

In my .ts file:

```
public fileChangeListener($event: any) {
 let selectedFiles=$event.target.files; //Object of Filelist
}
```

selectedFileList contain different types of file like image/jpg, image/png, application/javascript, application/pdf etc. I want to get a FileList Object with only image type file.How can I get it?

note: accept="image/*" in HTML input element do not work here.

```
{
lastModified:1521624250148,
lastModifiedDate:Wed Mar 21 2018 15:24:10 GMT+0600 (+06) {},
name:"rxlnn70l.bmp",
size:814138,
type:"image/bmp",
webkitRelativePath:"second/rxlnn70l.bmp",
}
```

Here in my code `error: files.slice is not a function`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: *"I want to get a FileList Object with only image type file"* You can't, since you can't construct them. But you can create an array of only the `File` objects you want from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow <input type="file"> to accept only image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828554/how-to-allow-input-type-file-to-accept-only-image-files)

Comment: this may not duplicate here I select file from directory chooser. accept attribute do not work in my case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use *spread operator* `...` to convert `FileList` to `Array` and filter the same by checking whether its `type` contains sub-text `'image'`.

```
   var files = e.target.files;
   files = [...files].filter( s => s.type.includes("image") )
```

**Demo**

```js
document.querySelector( "[type='file']" ).addEventListener( "change", function(e){
   var files = e.target.files;
   files = [...files].filter( s => s.type.includes("image") )
   console.log(files);
})
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

**Edit**

If spread operator is not supported in your browser, then use one of the following

```
files = Array.from(files).filter( function(s){ 
    return s.type.includes("image") ;
});
```

Or

```
files = [].slice.call(files).filter( function(s){ 
    return s.type.includes("image") ;
});
```

Comment: Your code is looks good in you demo. But in my project its throw an error like: 
`ERROR TypeError: files.slice is not a function`

my selected files do not contain slice property.

Comment: There is no `files.slice` in my code. Are you not using my code as is?

Comment: console result from your code:
`{
    "name": "rxlnn70l.bmp",
    "lastModified": 1521624250148,
    "lastModifiedDate": "2018-03-21T09:24:10.148Z",
    "webkitRelativePath": "second/rxlnn70l.bmp",
    "size": 814138,
    "type": "image/bmp",
    "slice": /**id:3**/ function slice() { [native code] }
  }`

from my code:

`{
    "name": "rxlnn70l.bmp",
    "lastModified": 1521624250148,
    "lastModifiedDate": "2018-03-21T09:24:10.148Z",
    "webkitRelativePath": "second/rxlnn70l.bmp",
    "size": 814138,
    "type": "image/bmp"

 //slice function is missing
  }`

Comment: @ShamimHossain Can you confirm if you have used the code I have shared, without spread operator as well?

Comment: Thanks. Its work now.

Comment: @ShamimHossain Sure, glad it worked for you.