# Display success or error message when file is upload using JavaScript or bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can we display success or error message when correct jpeg file is upload. Then show success message like that https://ibb.co/j64FTf2 and when file is upload incorrect or any another extension like png or gif then its show error message like that https://ibb.co/0MFwtQs using html CSS bootstrap JavaScript or jQuery.

```
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" required />
```

Comment: any one help me out

Comment: Hi Neha, you can set the ```accept``` attribute for the file. Such as ```accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"```

For more details please referrer this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6225815/1189070)

Comment: @HimanshuSaxena thanks for help this one is fine but when i upload the jpg file or png file then in display message show success how can we do that like this https://ibb.co/j64FTf2  https://ibb.co/0MFwtQs

Comment: Questions should be helpful to future readers. Instead of linking to an external site that may change in time, provide a working code example that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fileValidation() {
            let errorElement = document.getElementById("error");
            errorElement.innerHTML = "";
            var fileInput =  
                document.getElementById('file'); 
              
            var filePath = fileInput.value; 
          
            // Allowing file type 
            var allowedExtensions =  
                    /(\.jpg|\.jpeg)$/i; 
              
            if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) { 
                errorElement.innerHTML = "File type should be jpeg or jpg";
                fileInput.value = ''; 
                return false; 
            }  
            else  
            { 
              
                // Image preview 
                if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) { 
                    var reader = new FileReader(); 
                    reader.onload = function(e) { 
                        document.getElementById( 
                            'imagePreview').innerHTML =  
                            '<img src="' + e.target.result 
                            + '"/>'; 
                    }; 
                      
                    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]); 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file"
        onchange="return fileValidation()" />
        <div id="error"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for this but i want display mesage and here is alert message is showing