# ionic capacitor <input> file crash the app on android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have a simple Angular app, that has an
`<input type="file" id="file" accept=".png,.jpg"(change)="handleFileInput($event)">`
and when click the choose file button my app crashes with:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=601434129, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.piicco.app/com.piicco.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: showFileChooser result was already called
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5015)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5056)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: showFileChooser result was already called
```

However, when removing the `accept=".png,.jpg"` it works (but the user can select any types of file, which is bad)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow <input type="file"> to accept only image files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828554/how-to-allow-input-type-file-to-accept-only-image-files)

Comment: Use "accept='image/*'"

Comment: the crash was a bug, I've sent a PR for fixing it https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/pull/4707

Answer (score 0):

Using `accept="image/png, image/jpeg"` fixes the issue