# How to verify that a file is an image in JavaScript, when a non-image file is renamed with an image extension?

Tags: javascript, image

Is there any way in JavaScript to verify that an uploaded file is in fact an image?

Say I have a .exe file and I change the extension to .png.

Thanks.

Comment: You can look for the [magic bytes](https://www.netspi.com/blog/technical/web-application-penetration-testing/magic-bytes-identifying-common-file-formats-at-a-glance/) to identify a file format even when the extension has been changed, but I have no idea how you would implement this in JavaScript.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow <input type="file"> to accept only image files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828554/how-to-allow-input-type-file-to-accept-only-image-files)